# How to get total number of sku added in the cart?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, shipping-methods

In magento C.E 1.7, How to get **how many sku or product ids are added into the cart**. Not the quantity of products in the cart.

I need to get it in ../shippingmethod/**available.phtml** file to process different shipping methods based on number of items.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get shopping cart items count

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount()
```

Get Shopping cart product ids

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getProductIds()
```